# jquery - ajax code not behaving correctly

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm wondering what's wrong with my code? It's just not working right. The syntax looks good to me - basically, if a div called 'map_canvas' exists on the loaded page, then a function called initialize_google_maps should be called.

But the initialize_google_maps function is called sometimes even if map_canvas div doesn't exist on a page. To be more specific - it is always called the first time a link is clicked, even when no map_canvas exists, and then it behaves correctly.

```
$(document).on("ready", function(){

 console.log('load ajax when document starts'); 
  var ajax_loaded = (function(response) {        

    $(".page-content")

     .html($(response).filter(".page-content"));       

    $(".page-content .ajax").on("click",ajax_load);  


   });


//the function below is called by links that are described with the class 'ajax', or are in the div 'menu' 

var history = [];                 

var current_url_method;               

var ajax_load = (function(e) {  


console.log('load ajax on clicks');         
  e.preventDefault();               


  history.push(this);               
  var url =$(this).attr("href");          
  var method = $(this).attr("data-method");   

  if (current_url_method != url + method) {   
    console.log('url + method'); 
    current_url_method = url + method;      

    $.ajax({                  
      "url": url,               
      "type": method,                         
      "success": ajax_loaded,         
    });
   }

    if ($("#map_canvas").length > 0)
    {
      console.log('ajax 2 - map_canvas is detected'); 
      initialize_google_maps();

    }


});



$("#menu a").on("click",ajax_load);
$(".ajax").on("click",ajax_load);
$("#menu a.main").trigger("click");
$(".search-box form").on("submit", form_submit);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.ajax` is asynchronous by default. So essentially the code after the ajax call (where you are checking `$("#map_canvas").length`) gets executed before your ajax response is returned.

```
 $.ajax({                  
      "url": url,               
      "type": method,                         
      "success": ajax_loaded         
    });
```

The quick solution is to make the ajax call synchronous:

```
$.ajax({                  
  url: url,               
  type: method,  
  async: false,                       
  success: ajax_loaded       
});
```

**Caveat:** Syncronous calls are pretty nasty and lockup the browser, the better solution would be to perform the `$("#map_canvas").length` check in the response of the ajax object and keep the call asynchronous.

```
$.ajax({                  
  url: url,               
  type: method,  
  async: true,                       
  success: function(){
     //Running your secondary checks here will ensure that they
     // are executed only when the Ajax object has finished what it has to do.
  }       
});
```

Comment: It is better to remove the `,` before the `});`

Comment: True, I was copying and pasting from the original.

Comment: Thank you! I've actually spent DAYS trying to solve an ajax problem - too messy to put up here. I think this is a big piece of the puzzle.

Comment: sorry, just saw your caveat. Nasty? You mean lots of people mightn't be able to use my app at the same time or something? And what do you mean by the 'response of the ajax object' Sorry, pretty new to this.

Comment: By Nasty I mean that while you are reading the URL with the Ajax call (in sync mode) the browser locks up and waits for a response. Some browsers actually show the kill tab option when you do this (if it takes too long). The Ajax response is a nested function where you can execute code only when the Ajax function has finished what it has to do. I will illustrate in my answer.